# The bootsrap glyphs not displayed on SharePoint public site

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, css, public-website, boot-strap

I recently connected a domain to my public website on SharePoint Online (Developer tenant). When I connected the template with the master page and page layout works flawlessly on: https://domain-public.sharepoint.com/ but with the new domain:
http: //www.domain.se/ on the public web site deletes all button icons that should be in the file: font-awesome.min.css but the function remains.
But if I use Chrome appear as squares.

NOTE!
In all three cases, the function works!

Why is this happening in the public website?

Please check the attached pictures.[image: SP_]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the permissions on your Fonts folder wherever it is stored in your site. I think a simple explanation would be that public does not have read access to that folder.

Comment: Thank you so much. I agree with you, But how can I Edit the folder permission if not get anonymous users?

Comment: So basically your question is "how to give anonymous users access to your data?" which I don't know for SP online. For on-prem I would try "domain\everyone".

Answer (score 2):

This has probably nothing to do with SharePoint. Are you sure you're using the last version of bootstrap ?
I had the same issue one time, and I updated the fonts directory provided by bootstrap. Seemed like Chrome was having a problem with woff2 font files, I can't really remember.

Edit : I remember now, it was a problem with IIS, I had to update my web.config, you could try adding something like that in your web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```

If you don't succeed to solve your problem by then, I will be able to look at what I did on Wednesday.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respons. As I searches before it is not possible to access or modify the web.config file for a public-facing site with SharePoint Online. Otherwise, where can I find the web.config file?

Comment: Damn, I'm sorry I didn't take into account that you were using SharePoint Online. And please someone can correct if I'm wrong but I don't think you're able to add mime types to SharePoint Online for the moment. Sorry about that.